# How to handle response provided by the user in Actions on Google

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloud, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am facing a problem in handling random response by the user, like if there is a question in my 'Default welcome intent', `conv.ask('say a name');` then obviously it'll leave mic open and the user gives a response with some name like *Adam* or *Eve* or anything and I want to respond it like `You said Adam` ,or `You said Eve` ,  how can I do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire point of an Intent is to capture what the user says. So you can create another Intent that would try to match the user saying a name. Then you can handle this Intent in your fulfillment webhook. Perhaps something like this:

[image]

Comment: You can see almost the same case but with colors on AoG codelab here (part 1 and 2) https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/#0